# clang-11 (optimized build): why is gcovr line coverage of C++ code (compiled with -O2) not 100%

Tags: c++

I have the following C++-code:

```
 #include<stdexcept>
 #include<string>
 #include<cassert>
 
 class my_exception_t : public std::runtime_error {
    public:
     my_exception_t();
     ~my_exception_t() noexcept override;
 };
 
 class my_other_exception_t : public std::runtime_error {
    public:
     my_other_exception_t();
     ~my_other_exception_t() noexcept override;
 };
 
 class my_sub_exception_t : public my_exception_t {
    public:
     my_sub_exception_t();
     ~my_sub_exception_t() noexcept override;
 };
 
 my_exception_t::my_exception_t()
     : std::runtime_error("my-exception") {}
 my_exception_t::~my_exception_t() noexcept = default;
 
 my_other_exception_t::my_other_exception_t()
     : std::runtime_error("my-other-exception") {}
 my_other_exception_t::~my_other_exception_t() noexcept = default;
 
 my_sub_exception_t::my_sub_exception_t() : my_exception_t{} {}
 my_sub_exception_t::~my_sub_exception_t() noexcept = default;
 
 int main() {
     //TEST 1
     static_assert(std::is_base_of<std::runtime_error,
                                   my_exception_t>::value);
     my_exception_t me;
 
     //TEST 2
     static_assert(std::is_base_of<std::runtime_error,
                                   my_other_exception_t>::value);
     my_other_exception_t moe;
 
     //TEST 3
     static_assert(std::is_base_of<std::runtime_error,
                                   my_sub_exception_t>::value);
     static_assert(std::is_base_of<my_exception_t,
                                   my_sub_exception_t>::value);
     my_sub_exception_t mse;
 }
```

It works as expected, but I also want to check the code-coverage!
But when I compile the code with clang++-11 and the flags `-O2`, execute the binary and run `govr` on it, I can see that the line with the definition of the destruct `~my_sub_exception()` is not covered:

I am executing the following calls:

```
$ clang++-11 -O2 -coverage -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -Werror -pedantic-errors -Wno-global-constructors -std=c++17 -o ex.cpp.o -c ex.cpp
$ clang++-11 ex.cpp.o -o ex -coverage
$ ./ex
$ gcovr -r . --gcov-executable="llvm-cov-11 gcov"
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           GCC Code Coverage Report
Directory: .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                                       Lines    Exec  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ex.cpp                                        13      12    92%   32
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                         13      12    92%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note: I get full coverage, if I use `clang++-11` with `-O0`.
(I also get full coverage, if I am using `g++-11` with both `-O2` and `-O0`).
But why not for clang++-11 with `-O2`?

As far as I observed the issue, I get this uncovered line only for exceptions which inherit from `my_exception_t`. If the exception class is inherited from `std::runtime_error`, there is no line coverage missing.

Comment: I'm wondering, as clang++-11 with `-O2` [will eliminate](https://godbolt.org/z/enMYG9ord) your test cases

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps due to the fact that all your `my_exception`s are global (static) variables, and thus there is no need to destroy anything (they will just go away when the process finishes).

To really answer, you'd have to hire your very own C++ language lawyer and clang++ expert.

Comment: But I can't see any static variables anywhere in this code. And why is the destructor called for the exceptions that directy inherit from `std::runtime_error`?